# How to write a java varg function in clojure?

Tags: clojure

In Java, a varg function can be written like this:

```
public static void foo(int ... a) 
{
   // method body
}
```

It gets called in Java like this:

```
<OBJ>.foo(1, 2, 3);
```

and it gets called in Clojure like this:

```
(<OBJ>/foo (int-array [1 2 3])
```

Is it possible to write `foo` in Clojure so that it gets called in Java as a varg function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is [no option](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/HMpMavh0WxA) to make Java-style varargs methods (that is, methods that accept arrays and have the VARARGS (0x80) bit set to true).

Instead, you can either make a function that accepts an array (and write a varargs wrapper around it in Java, if you need varargs) or make a Clojure's `[&rest]` function and `.invoke()` it with varargs.